# Displaying at least 100 videos on a single Web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I would like to display a webpage with a wall of very short videos:

- The videos are 1-2s long and all the same size (about 100px wide)
- They are display in the form of a matrix (e.g. 10x10)
- Playing the videos is triggered by user interaction (click or hover)

So far, I have tried inserting video tags using jQuery but when I reach about 60 videos, my browser (Chrome) hangs.

My question: is there a trick to display such a large quantity of videos on a single web page and what issue should I look out for to make sure the videos are ready to play before the user starts to interact.

EDIT: I understand this isn't common practice, but this project is an art installation and I need to be able to trigger all the videos (or moving images) on demand and without delay. On the other hand, the initial loading time doesn't matter so much, as the user will be made aware of the heavy load.

Thanks :)

Comment: you can try to just show a list of images and when the user clicks a specific image the video starts loading & playing.

Answer (score 0):

IMO "videos are ready (...) before the user starts to interact" contradicts a leightweight DOM. You cannot have both. I'd try to show thumbnails and initialize the video with the interaction.

Comment: Yes I agree with this in general. But this specific case is an art installation, so I need all the videos ready to play without delay. The initial loading time doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use the

use the

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="embed Link" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

tag inside of html. then you can acces every object by giving it a tag